# jQuery bind to dynamic image error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is called on page load and then again every 30 seconds to update the camera feed. My problem is that some times the cameras that I am loading do not have an image generated and it throws a 503 error.

I am trying to bind to `img` and replace any images that fail with a placeholder image so that there is no big white gap on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   // Listen for image errors
   $("img").bind("error", function () {
     $(this).attr("src", "assets/img/img_not_available.gif?v=2");
   });

   updateFeeds();

});

function updateFeeds() {

  // Define our variables
  var content = '';

  // Load our JSON file
  $.getJSON("./cameras.json", function (result) {

    // Loop through each of the cameras and create our HTML string
    $(result.cameras).each(function (k, v) {
      content +=
        '<div class="card">' +
        '<a href="' + baseURL + v.imageName + '" target="_blank">' +
        '<div class="cam">' +
        '<img class="img-fluid" src="' + baseURL + v.imageName + '?r=' + timestamp + '" alt="' + v.intersection + ' Camera Down">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</a>' +
        '<p class="card-text">' + v.intersection + '</p>' +
        '</div>';
    });

    // Append our data to the DOM
    $('#cameras').empty().append(content);

    // Update the last update time
    updateRefreshTime();

  });

}
```

How can I replace an image that fails to load? I put a `console.log` inside the bind function and it never executes when an image fails to load. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You want to check the status code, returning from requested URL, m I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if image is available or not inside the `.each` loop like this:

```
$(result.cameras).each(function (k, v) {
      if(v.imageName == '')    // Checking if image is not available.
        v.imageName = 'assets/img/img_not_available.gif?v=2';    // Assign placeholder image path.
      content +=
        '<div class="card">' +
        '<a href="' + baseURL + v.imageName + '" target="_blank">' +
        '<div class="cam">' +
        '<img class="img-fluid" src="' + baseURL + v.imageName + '?r=' + timestamp + '" alt="' + v.intersection + ' Camera Down">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</a>' +
        '<p class="card-text">' + v.intersection + '</p>' +
        '</div>';
    });
```

Comment: It's not the image name that is missing, its the actual image hosted on an external server. If it doesn't exist. it will throw an error which is what I need to check for.

Comment: The op said that 503 is being returned, so I guess there is a link but it doesn't return the image.

Comment: @SBB, you mean you are getting image link in JSON but you can not check if the image is present on the server to which the link points. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

If no `src` value has responded then hook the `onerror` javascript event, try to update image line as below:

```
'<img class="img-fluid" src="' + baseURL + v.imageName + '?r=' + timestamp + '" alt="' + v.intersection + ' Camera Down"  onerror="this.src=\'assets/img/img_not_available.gif?v=2\'">' +
```

Please give your feedback in the comment. Thanks